# Decoding base64 strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to decode base64 string in PHP.

For example, I can do this in a python script by doing:

```
s = "0CC0QFjAA"
base64.b64decode(str(s)+'=====', '_-');
```

How can I decode base64 strings in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: @hjpotter92, `base64_decode` cannot handle alternative characters.

Comment: I think you could use `str_replace()` to implement `altchars`.

Comment: @barmar alternative characters are required during decoding not before or after so str_replace would not work

Comment: @Vineet1982,  Please provide valid base64-encoded string. Your code raises `TypeError`.

Comment: @falsetru It is the valid string running correctly in PYTHON

Comment: @Vineet1982, Does not work in both Python 2 and Python 3. See http://ideone.com/FpejTC

Comment: The Python documentation isn't very clear, but it looks to me like the altchars simply replace the characters `+` and `/` in the encoded form. I don't know what you mean by _required during decoding_, it seems to me that just undoing this replacement in the encoded string is all you need.

Comment: @Vineet1982: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do it:

```
$decoded = base64_decode(str_replace(array('_', '-'), array('+', '/'), $s));
```

If you need the more general form:

```
function b64decode($str, $altchars = null) {
    if ($altchars) {
        $altarray = array($altchars[0], $altchars[1]);
        $str = str_replace($altarray, array('+', '/'), $str);
    }
    return base64_decode($str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The PHP function is called `base64_decode`. You could call it like `base64_decode($s);`

Comment: what about python altchars

Comment: Are you talking about encoding? Like UTF-8?

Comment: @Jordan, See [base64.b64decode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64#base64.b64decode).

Comment: @Jordan He's talking about the optional second argument to `b64decode()`: _Optional altchars must be a string of at least
length 2 (additional characters are ignored) which specifies the
alternative alphabet used instead of the '+' and '/' characters._

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, but he changed the question since the time I answered.